# Получение всех методов пакета

Tags: java

Как узнать все методы пакета? С помощью Reflections понял, как получить методы класса, но как получить все методы пакета?

Comment: Найти все классы, найти все методы каждого класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Найти все классы данного пакета, например так (не проверял, но должно выдавать, то что вам надо)

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(ClasspathHelper
   .forPackage("my.package.prefix"), new SubTypesScanner());
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

2) Получить все методы от всех классов (но это вы уже вроде знаете):

```
Set<Method> result = new HashSet<>();
for(Class cls: subTypes) {
   result.addAll(Arrays.asList(cls.getDeclaredMethods()));
   result.addAll(Arrays.asList(cls.getMethods())); 
   // важно использовать обе метода, так как getMethods возвращает 
   // только публичные методы, включая унаследованные, а getDeclaredMethods 
   // возвращает и приватные, протектед методы, но не унаследованные 
}
```

Comment: Разве `getDeclaredMethods` не возвращает ВСЕ методы?

Comment: Нет! Это большая ошибка так думать, getDeclaredMethods не вернет никаких методов унаследованных о родителя/родителей (даже если они публичные). Это может быть очень опасным заблуждением.

Comment: Из javadoc'a: This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.

Answer (score 3):

Рефлексия - это механизм, с помощью которого можно на этапе выполнения работать с классами и объектами, неизвестными на этапе компиляции. Если Вам надо искать пакеты и их содержимое, обратитесь не к рефлексии , а к пакету IO, ведь пакет по сути - не что иное, как обычная папка. Берите относительный путь, пробуйте докопаться до нужного пакета, хранящего классы, получайте их список, формируйте имена, а потом по имени класса рефлексией получайте методы каждого из них. А искать методы пакета... Ну таких просто не бывает, методы бывают только в классе. А вообще задача ваша изначально странная.